# Swagger boolean parameter value True/False instead of true/false and django_filters

Tags: django, swagger, swagger-ui, django-filter, django-filters

Swagger UI submits boolean params in 'true/false' form, while django filter boolean field expects True/False (uppercase). Therefore when I query through swagger, the field **is_published**  has no effect.

```
{{api_url}}/api/v1/games/?limit=10&offset=0&is_published=true
{{api_url}}/api/v1/games/?limit=10&offset=0&is_published=false
```

**Filter field is defined as**

```
is_published = BooleanFilter(name='versions__is_published')
```

**full definition**

```
class GameFilter(FilterSet):
    """Custom filter for ``GameViewSet``.

    Defines custom filter for ``genres`` field (based on TaggableManager).

    """

    is_published = BooleanFilter(name='versions__is_published')

    class Meta:
        model = Game

        fields = {
            'platforms':  ['exact'],
            'ages':       ['exact'],
            'developers': ['exact'],
            'genres':     ['exact'],
            'created':    ['gt', 'lt']
        }
```

**Swagger definition of the method**

```
get:
  summary: Get list of games
  operationId: getGamesList
  parameters:
    - $ref: '../../parameters.yaml#/Offset'
    - $ref: '../../parameters.yaml#/Limit'
    - $ref: '../../parameters.yaml#/PlatformsFilter'
    - $ref: '../../parameters.yaml#/DevelopersFilter'
    - $ref: '../../parameters.yaml#/GenresFilter'
    - $ref: '../../parameters.yaml#/AgesFilter'
    - $ref: '../../parameters.yaml#/SearchFilter'
    - $ref: '../../parameters.yaml#/Order'
    - name: is_published
      in: query
      type: boolean
      required: false
      default: true
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**solution**:

The base django_filters.FilterSet is intended to be used with vanilla Django views. If you're creating an API with DRF, you should use django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet as it uses a slightly different set of filters that is more suitable for use in an API. In this case, the BooleanFilter accepts lowercase true/false values.

**After adjusted import:**

```
from django_filters import ModelMultipleChoiceFilter
from django_filters.rest_framework import BooleanFilter, FilterSet
```